# How do I create WebRole for Azure using command-line tools(SDK) for linux

Tags: azure

I am working on Ubuntu and installed the Azure SDK for Linux and got it working. Using the Linux SDK how do I add  Azure WebRole for a node.js service.

I was referring the following tutorial but it only discusses how to create WebRole using cmdlet on Windows

[Node.js Cloud Service](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/getting-started/)

Also looked into following link that explains Azure command line for Linux/Mac but I am not able to find any command for creating WebRole using linux SDK

[Windows Azure command-line tool for Mac and Linux](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/other-resources/command-line-tools/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You CAN NOT  create WEB ROLE (If you mean a Windows Azure Web Role) in Windows Azure by using "[Windows Azure command-line tool for Mac and Linux](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/other-resources/command-line-tools/)" because these command are only use with your Virtual Machine Linux (as well as Windows too). Also the [Node.js Cloud Service](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/getting-started/) link above will create a Node.js web server in a Windows Azure Virtual Machine so be sure what you are trying to do here. This will not work in your Virtual Machine.

However if you want to create a Linux VM and the run Web Server on it then it sure if possible using the exact commands and the steps will be as below:

1. Create a Linux VM (upload your own or [create VM directly by Linux Gallery Image](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/how-to-guides/custom-create-a-vm/))
2. [Setup Putty to login to your Linux VM](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/how-to-guides/log-on-a-linux-vm/)
3. Install Web Server of your choice using [info here](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/common-tasks/install-software/) over Putty command session

Let me know if you need help in any of above step.

Comment: I was trying to use the sites feature on Windows Azure to deploy a node.js application using git publishing. It requires configuring a WebRole and the [Node.js Cloud Service](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/getting-started/) article has a step for creating WebRole but using windows cmdlet. I thought Linux SDK should provide equivalent functionality and was looking for a command to do the same. But looks like Linux SDK has limited support for managing roles/workers sites and configuring

Comment: Yes, you are right. Linux SDK provide commands to manage Virtual Machines mainly.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the source of the Linux CLI ([service.js](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/cli/commands/service.js)) and it looks like there is no way to create a hosted service (which would contain your web role) through the command line.

The only operations available are:

- list
- delete [name]
- portal [name]